# can't use curl to query neo4j

Tags: windows, shell, curl, neo4j

I am trying to use curl to query neo4j

```
curl -X POST -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -u neo4j:password -v http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) RETURN n"}]}'
```

gives me this response

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:7474...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7474 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'neo4j'
> POST /db/neo4j/tx/commit HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7474
> Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept:application/json
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 47
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 09:13:35 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 120
<
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Could not parse the incoming JSON"}]}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

If anyone could help please

Comment: I tried it on my system it worked, using postman.

Comment: That looks correct indeed: https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request/.
Have you tried the same query with Neo4j browser on http://localhost:7474? Maybe there's an issue with your local setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have mentioned I'm on windows. Apparently you have to escape those double quotes in the json

This works for me now:

```
curl -X POST -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -u neo4j:password -v http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit -d "{\"statements\":[{\"statement\":\"MATCH (n) RETURN n\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had troubles sending Cypher to Neo4j through Http, it was ok with simple `MATCH (n) RETURN n`, but when my query used apoc procedure, curly braces and params, I was getting `Could not parse the incoming JSON` error as well. So below are my solutions. Both commands are for Powershell, not CMD.

Basically, since we enclosed text block with single quotes, the only char that needs to be escaped is single quote, and we escape it with another single quote.

### Send Cypher by Curl

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://neo4j:qwertyuiop@localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit -d '{"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (nod:Person) MATCH ()-[rels:HAS_CHILD]->() WITH collect(nod) as a, collect(rels) as b CALL apoc.export.json.data(a, b, null, { jsonFormat: ''JSON'', stream: true}) YIELD data RETURN data;"}]}'
```

### Send Cypher with Invoke-WebRequest

```
invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("neo4j:qwertyuiop"))} -Body '{"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (nod:Person) MATCH ()-[rels:HAS_CHILD]->() WITH collect(nod) as a, collect(rels) as b CALL apoc.export.json.data(a, b, null, { jsonFormat: ''JSON'', stream: true}) YIELD data RETURN data;"}]}'
```